# Finding the kernel of these matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find the kernel for each these matrices:
\begin{equation}
A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 3 & 1 \end{array}\right] \qquad B = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
AB = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 10 \end{array}\right] \qquad BA = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 6 & 9 & 3 \\ -2 & -3 & -1 \end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

My solutions are as follows:
\begin{equation}
\ker(A) = \ker(BA) = \left\{\left(-\frac{3}{2}s - \frac{1}{2}t,s,t\right):s,t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ker(B) = \ker(AB) = 0
\end{equation}

I am wondering whether or not these are correct.

Also, is this the right way of writing this solution?

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning behind $\ker(A)=\ker(BA)$ and $\ker(B)=\ker(AB)$?

Comment: For $\ker(A)$ I noticed that the row in $A$ will only be zero when $x = -\frac{3}{2}s - \frac{1}{2}t$, where $y = s$ and $z = t$ (free variables). For $\ker(BA)$ I carried out the row reduction and ended up with only the top row (which is the same as the row matrix $A$). For $\ker(B)$ it is obvious that the rows are only zero when $x = 0$. For $\ker(AB)$, again it is obvious that the row is only zero when $x = 0$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, except that you don't need the $,s,t$ in the parenthesis. For the second one, maybe add curly brackets around $0$.